# Expressing three recursive forms into one using parameters?

Tags: functions, notation, recursion

I have the following recursive function that takes three forms and I want to express it in one form:

Initial: $f(x) = m * f(x-1)$, $f(0) = value.$

Forms:

1 - $f(t) = m * f(t-1)$. where t is at $+\infty$. So I want to start from the basic value at $t=0$ and then keep applying this to infinity. i.e. I want $f(x)$ where $x=\infty$.

2 - $f(t) = m * f(t-1)$. where $t >= 0$. I want to apply this starting from the basic value at $t=0$ and end at some value $t=k$ that I specify. So $f(x)$ where $x = k$.

3- $f(t) = \sum_{i}^{t}{m*f(i)}$. Here the function gets evaluated as $mf(1) + mf(2) +...+mf(t)$.

What I'm looking for is to express the three forms into one form that I can just manipulate it by changing parameters.

This is how I'm trying to do it, but I'm not sure if my *mathematical* expression is correct.

Compact form: $f(t) = \sum_{i}^{k}{m*f(i)}$

Form 1: $t = +\infty, k=1, i=+\infty$. This is definitely wrong I guess because $i$ can't start at $+\infty$ and end at $1$.

Form 2: $t = c, k=1, i=c$. This has the same issue as the previous step. I just want to evaluate the function at $t=c$ without any summation.

Form 3: $t=k$.

As you can see I have a problem to translate the forms into one compact form. I hope you can help.

Comment: For your first function, the simplest I can conceive is  
$f(t)=a m^t$ with $f(0)=a$. Your opinion, please.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  actually I simplified this example a lot. I'm actually working with vectors and matrices. My true $f(x)$ function is a vector. $\vec{\pi}(t) = m * P^T * \vec{\pi}(t-1)$ where $\vec{\pi}(0)$ is a vector $n*1$ and $P^T$ is a square $n*n$ matrix.

Comment: I fear that in simplifying, some meaning has been lost.  The three "forms" do not appear to be varying presentations of one underlying functions.  Indeed form 3 appears to be a circular definition, in that $f(t)$ is made to be a sum of things including (if I read it correctly) $m*f(t)$.

Comment: @hardmath I was thinking about a quadratic form: $f(t)=\sum_{i}^k{\sum_{l}^i{f(l)}}$ But it is also not correct

Comment: @AlexTwain. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @hardmath I see what you mean. I guess this is the essence of what I'm trying to do here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678518/combining-two-functions-in-a-parameterized-function